# swift json serialization error : Unable to convert data to string

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, jsonserializer

I'm a Korean developer, and I'm not familiar with swift.

Unfortunately the server I need to connect with is encoded in euc-kr format.
If the JSON contains Korean, it outputs the following error: Unable to convert data to string

I have verified through Json Parser that the shape of my JSON is not strange.
I am using Alamofire library for server connection.

This is my Json structure.

```
{"result":[{"id":"2659","member_id":"sexyback","nickname":"BJ%ED%8F%AC%EB%A1%9C%EB%A6%AC","live_YN":"N","19":"all","intro":"엄청나게 재미있는 포로리","fan":"open","acc_good":"","acc_fav":"","img_url":"%2Fpx%2Ffiles%2Fdotv_2659_f1_657.jpg"}],"total":[{"total":"6"}],"status":[{"status":"success"}]}
```

My logic is:

```
static func requestHotBJList() async -> Any {
    
    let url = WebConstant.getHotBJList()
    DLogUtil.debug(tag: #file, content: url)
    
    do {
        let data = try await HttpWrapper.requestGetTest(withUrl: url)
        return JSONUtil.createJSONObject(data: data)
    } catch {
        return error
    }
}
```

Get data from server via Http Wrapper.request Get. Try JSON Parsing through `JSONUtil.createJSONObject(data: data)` with the data of the Data type imported from here.

I get data from the server in the following way:

```
public static func requestGet(
    withUrl url: String,
    withHeader header: HTTPHeaders? = nil
) async throws -> Data {
 
    try await withUnsafeThrowingContinuation { continuation in
       
        AF.request(url, method: .get, headers: header).validate().responseData { response in
            if let data = response.data {
                continuation.resume(returning: data)
                return
            }
            if let error = response.error {
                continuation.resume(throwing: error)
                return
            }
            fatalError("fatal error")
        }
    }
}
```

The data parsing logic is as follows :

```
public static func createJSONObject(data: Data) -> [String : Any] {
    
    do {
        DLogUtil.debug(tag: #file, content: "data ? \(data)")
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String : Any]
        return json
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        DLogUtil.debug(tag: #file, content: error)
       

        return [String : Any]()
    }
}
```

Error is output during the parsing process. I've searched a lot, but I can't find it.

Comment: could you add `print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))` just before `do {...}` in your `createJSONObject` function,
and comment out the lines with `DLogUtil`. Then show us what it prints.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine DLogUtil is similar to print. It is just to check which file the print is output from.

As you said, when I print, nothing is printed. Data that does not contain Korean will be output normally.

Comment: try using this `.utf16`

Comment: what system are you using? All works well for me using your json data, and decoding it, with `.utf8` and`. utf16`.
On macos 12.5, using Xcode 13.3, targets ios-15 macCatalyst 12.3.

Comment: have you looked at this SO post regarding `euc-kr`  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41270687/swift-euc-kr-korean-encoding-not-working-but-works-in-python  That may provide you with a solution.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Thanks. 
It doesn't quite match the method you provided, but based on this method, I did some research and found a way. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

With help from @workingdogsupportUkraine, I found a way. After converting data type to NSString, NSString is encoded in utf-8 format.

```
            var dataString = NSString(data: data, encoding: CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(0x0422))
        var datadata = dataString!.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: datadata!, options: []) as! [String : Any]

        return json
```